# Window resize undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why I get an error when I console.log a message on window resize in this jQuery plugin. Can I not reference the window from within the Plugin prototype?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  "use strict";

  var pluginName = "rigallery",
    defaults = {
      transition: "ease"
    };

  function Plugin ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      this.getHeight();
    },
    getHeight: function() {
      $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log('Yay!');
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
    this.each(function() {
      if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
      }
    });
    return this;
  };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: ;(function  looks suspicious to me

Comment: By *window resize* you mean window reload?

Comment: @Steve It's legal. The semicolon as the first character is a common practice to ensure all previous statements have been terminated. The wrapped function is an [iife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: I don't believe jQuery has a `.reload()` event. Change it to `.resize()` and you'll probably fix the error.

Comment: Why are you passing the window object as a parameter when it's global?

Comment: This keeps the plugin from conflicting with any other Javascript that might not have ended in a semicolon. I know this part is right.

Comment: Freaxy: How should I be doing it? window.resize(function()... ?

Comment: @Freaxy The OP is creating a closure via an [iife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). By passing the `window` property, he/she is effectively creating a "private" variable that contains the `window` context.

Comment: Unless you call the `getHeight` function, you're resize event will never be bound.

Comment: It seem like it is working : http://jsfiddle.net/mmyfzj1b/. But you are binding a resize event for every element in the initial jQuery stack, which is bad...

Comment: This code works for me as well

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm not sure what you mean. It still isn't working on my end for some reason. The goal is for every time the window resizes, my image gallery (didn't put the code in for you to see for this) adjusts it's height.

Comment: It seems to throw the error on the $(window).resize line.

Comment: Works for me. How are you trying to call it? `$(document).rigallery()` or `$(window).rigallery()` seems to work.

Comment: I can't tell you why it is not working for you, but i can explain the second part of my comment. Every time you call `getHeight`, you bind a new event on the window resize. `getHeight` is beign called inside `init`. `init` is called when you use `new Plugin()` which is used into an each loop. Multiple resize events are binded on the window if you original selector return multiple elements.

Comment: @Freaxy $(function() {$("section > div").rigallery();});

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon So instead inside init() I should be doing a $(window).resize(function() {getHeight();}); ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I moved the window.resize call to the init method, and then added a var that = this and then called the getHeight using that.getHeight(). I would be interested to know if this is the correct way to do this.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  "use strict";

  var pluginName = "rigallery",
    defaults = {
      transition: "ease"
    };

  function Plugin ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      var that = this;
      this.createGallery();
      this.slidesTransition();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log(that.getHeight());
      });
    },
    getHeight: function() {
      var height = $(this.element).find("li:first img").height();
      return height;
    }
  };

  $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
    this.each(function() {
      if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
      }
    });
    return this;
  };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```